# Error developing web project + api + SQL Server + dotnet

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, .net-core

I have to develop a small project that accesses a SQL Server table and returns a JSON on HTTP-REST. I tested a direct project to access my `program.cs` direct database and it worked, but when I tried to integrate a basic Web API project, and squeegee my project does not appear to me either in the index or in the `GET` route.

Base configuration (`appsettings.json`):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectAppDatabase": "Server=<my_domain>.database.windows.net;Database=<my_base>;user id=<my_user>;password=<my_password>"
  }
```

Rota (`launchSettings.json`)

```
..."connect_app": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "connectAppController",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

(Startup.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<connectAppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectAppDatabase")));
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

In my controller the index is just a static page, in the get route I want to return to a query

```
https://localhost:5001/api/connectapp/getmensage?codigo=<code_example>

namespace Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class connectAppController : Controller
    {
        private readonly connectAppContext _context;

        public connectAppController(connectAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Console.Write("Index");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet("{codigo:length(12)}", Name = "getmessage")]
        public ActionResult<byte[]> Get(string cod)
        {
            if (cod == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var mensage = _context.mensages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.codigo == cod);
            if (mensage == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            byte[] jsonUtf8Bytes;

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                WriteIndented = true
            };

            jsonUtf8Bytes = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(mensage, options);
            return jsonUtf8Bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the project it does not return me any errors, but when accessing url, I only get the default message 404 - page not found

```
shinier01@shinier01:~/Projetos/Connect-cargo/connect-app$ dotnet run info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/shinier01/Projetos/Connect-cargo/connect-app
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? if hand is this how do I connect with a SQL Server database? Or some configuration / command in my functions?

**UPDATE**

From what I can see from my debug, it opens the web browser on the route `https://localhost:5001`, the error message appears, but never passes the breakpoint that is in `Index()`

Comment: You have multiple pieces of code that return `NotFound`. Did you try [debugging your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)? Set a breakpoint to see how your code behaves? Or add logging?

Comment: but when index access has nothing that could return not found

Comment: and when I debug and try to call my route nothing appears on my console

Comment: The only thing I noticed on my debug console is that every now and then this message pops up "" Thread 7676 terminated with code 0 "

Comment: What "error message"?

Comment: This localhost's page could not be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https: // localhost: 5001 /
HTTP ERROR 404

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

to

```
[Route("api")]
```

then run the application and call

```
https://localhost:5001/api/getmessage?codigo=<cod_exemple>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make at least my page access the route and appear debug, but now is returning an error

> invalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionaryFactory' has
>   been registered.

I commented on my controller

```
//[Route("api")]
//[ApiController]
```

and added it to my Startup.cs Configure

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
          name: "default",
          pattern: "{controller=connectApp}/{action=Index}/");
});
```